# Flutter List UI

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

I am correctly building an application with flutter and while searching for some ideas i came across this list and I wanted to ask how I can get these results?

https://dribbble.com/shots/15932824--Transactions-Overview-Detailview

The last image where it says 30 June 2021, under that the list is like connected is there a way to achieve this? Thanks in advance I hope I was clear.

Comment: You can archive this with nested listview handling. outerListview header contains date & amount & its child contain another child which is also listView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> dispalyList = [
    {
      "date": "30 june 2021",
      "amount": "10000",
      "items": [
        {
          "product": "Fintroy",
          "amount": "100",
          "product_desc": "Purchase on site",
        },
        {
          "product": "Consta coffee",
          "amount": "5",
          "product_desc": "Purchase on store",
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "date": "24 june 2021",
      "amount": "5000",
      "items": [
        {
          "product": "ATM Withdrow",
          "amount": "100",
          "product_desc": "Sale earnings",
        },
        {
          "product": "Consta coffee",
          "amount": "4",
          "product_desc": "Purchase on shop",
        },
      ]
    }
  ];
  MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: dispalyList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final List<Map<String, dynamic>> productList =
                dispalyList[index]["items"];
            return Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(dispalyList[index]["date"] ?? ""),
                    const Spacer(),
                    Text(dispalyList[index]["amount"] ?? ""),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 12),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                      borderRadius:
                          const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12))),
                  child: ListView.separated(
                    physics:
                        const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), // AVOID CHILD LISTVIEW SCROLL
                    separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: productList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            const CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(width: 8),
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(productList[index]["product"]),
                                Text(productList[index]["product_desc"])
                              ],
                            ),
                            const Spacer(),
                            Text(productList[index]["amount"])
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 12),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much I am trying it out now. My problem is that the list i get is from API call and its not working very well, I have to adjust some things.

Comment: most welcome. yes, you have to manage your API call data in above listView and need to update UI as per requirement.share your api response code if you facing any issue. happy coding:)